# Iterating through an API response in XMl format and gathering data

Tags: groovy

I have a question about how to iterate through an XML API response and gather data.

Let's say I get an API reply in XML format. The reply looks like this;

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <SearchRS>
      <SearchStatus>SUCCESS</SearchStatus>
      <Itinerary>
           <DisplayTotal>189.41</DisplayTotal>  
           <FareStarProfileID>11PUB2</FareStarProfileID>
      </Itinerary>
      <Itinerary>
            <DisplayTotal>19.41</DisplayTotal>  
            <FareStarProfileID>11PUB3</FareStarProfileID>
      </Itinerary>
      <Itinerary>
            <DisplayTotal>79.11</DisplayTotal>  
            <FareStarProfileID>11PUB8</FareStarProfileID>
      </Itinerary>
      <Itinerary>
           <DisplayTotal>89.61</DisplayTotal>   
           <FareStarProfileID>11PUB4</FareStarProfileID>
      </Itinerary>
 </SearchRS>
```

Now I can iterate through these tickets and easily do things like find the highest, lowest and average price, get the totals for each location, etc by using this:

```
 def doc = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlResponse)
 doc.Ticket.each { Ticket ->
     // for each ticket in the xml response
     Ticket.children().each { tag ->
          // for each tag within each ticket
          switch(tag.name()) {
               case "Price":
                    [compute some stuff here]
               case "Location":
                    [compute some stuff here]
          etc....
```

My question is what if I wanted to find out the cheapest DisplayTotal for each FareStarProfileId? What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So given some XML like so:

```
def xmlResponse = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <SearchRS>
      <SearchStatus>SUCCESS</SearchStatus>
      <Itinerary>
           <DisplayTotal>189.41</DisplayTotal>  
           <FareStarProfileID>11PUB2</FareStarProfileID>
      </Itinerary>
      <Itinerary>
            <DisplayTotal>19.41</DisplayTotal>  
            <FareStarProfileID>11PUB3</FareStarProfileID>
      </Itinerary>
      <Itinerary>
            <DisplayTotal>79.11</DisplayTotal>  
            <FareStarProfileID>11PUB8</FareStarProfileID>
      </Itinerary>
      <Itinerary>
           <DisplayTotal>89.61</DisplayTotal>   
           <FareStarProfileID>11PUB4</FareStarProfileID>
      </Itinerary>
 </SearchRS>'''
```

You can use `groupBy` and `min` to achieve this:

```
def doc = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlResponse)

// Group Itinerary by profile text, then for each profile, just keep
// the lowest price one
def minTotals = doc.Itinerary.groupBy { it.FareStarProfileID.text() }
                   .collectEntries { profile, nodes ->
                       [profile, nodes.min { it.DisplayTotal.text() as Double }]
                   }

// minTotals is a map of FareStarProfileID -> xml node representing the itinerary...
// Lets print them out
minTotals.each { profile, minimum ->
    println "For profile $profile, the minimum is ${minimum.DisplayTotal}"
}
```

#### For Groovy 2.0.8

You can't do much with NodeChildren in 2.0.8, so you have to switch to use `inject` in place of `groupBy`

```
def minTotals = doc.Itinerary
        .inject([:].withDefault { [] }) { map, it ->
            map[it.FareStarProfileID.text()] << it
            map
        }
        .collectEntries { profile, nodes ->
           [profile, nodes.min { it.DisplayTotal.text() as Double }]
        }
```

Comment: If I apply that to my code I get this error: No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren.groupBy() is applicable for argument types

Comment: @Sulteric, have you tried the solution as it is first before you apply it to your xml?

Comment: That code simply won't work, it always fails at runtime and I can't find any example on the web to compare it to.

Comment: Works for me... What are you running?

Comment: Initellij 2017.1.5, Grails 2.2.5, Java version is 1.7

Comment: So either your XML is different to the question, or you are running different code... Paste the above into the groovy console. Does it work?

Comment: I'm still trying to get this to work. When I see "location, nodes ". Where is "location" (lowercase location) defined?

Comment: No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren.groupBy() is applicable for argument types: (comparomatic.ApiService$_executeApi_closure1) values: [comparomatic.ApiService$_executeApi_closure1@47cbee76]
Possible solutions: grep(), grep(java.lang.Object). Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren.groupBy() is applicable for argument types: (comparomatic.ApiService$_executeApi_closure1) values: [comparomatic.ApiService$_executeApi_closure1@47cbee76]
Possible solutions: grep(), grep(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Trying not to give away company info. Let me update the original post and we'll try again.

Comment: Okay, let's try again, I appreciate your patience with this. Original post updated.

Comment: The XML in the question isn't valid as it has no root node

Comment: Fixed it, all set now.

Comment: It works in groovy console but not in my grails project. I don't have enough experience to understand why.

Comment: Still the groupby exception in grails?

Comment: I'll do some digging and find the groovy version bundled with that grails

Comment: Yes, same groupBy exception. I don't understand it but it must be a version issue.

Comment: We're using Grails 2.2.5 which means groovy 2.0.8

Comment: I'll get that version downloaded and have a go 

Comment: Got it...  added it to the bottom of the answer... fingers crossed 

Comment: Hooray!  Have fun!

Comment: For some reason this is no longer working. Same exact grails//groovy version. It's failing at the .inject. No clue as to why. Is there an easier perhaps more understandable way to do this?

Comment: I have no idea why, or what your error is... Maybe a new question?